# Since my manifest file is embeded, why is it still created during publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I publish my application, an *application.exe.manifest* file is created in the publish folder, eventhough it is already embeded in my PE.
Do users need the manifest file for some reason?

Comment: Crystal ball says that you are looking at a ClickOnce manifest.  Yes, it is needed.  Do make sure you meant to use ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: Does the ClickOnce manifest has a _.manifest_ file extension?